# What is meant by "real-valued argument" in this context of the convolution operation?

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, terminology, convolution, books

Consider the following statement from [Deep Learning book (p. 327, chapter 9: Convolutional Networks)](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/convnets.html)

> In its most general form, convolution is an operation on two functions
> **of a real-valued argument**.

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are functions on which I want to apply convolution operation. What is meant by two functions of a "real-valued argument" in this context?

Does it mean $f$ and $g$  are real-valued functions? Or does it mean $f$ and $g$  are real functions? or any other?

- *Real-valued function:* Function whose codomain is a subset of real numbers
- *Real function:* Function whose domain and codomain are a subset of real numbers.

Answer (score 1):

In its most raw form, convolution is defined as: $(f*g)(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\tau) \cdot g(t-\tau) d\tau$.

Here, *t* doesn't represent the time domain. Infact, it represents the real valued argument the book is talking about. In this notion, at moment *t*, convolution can be thought of as a weighted average of the function $f(\tau)$ weighted by $g(–\tau)$, which is simply shifted by amount *t*.

Comment: Oh, the domains for both f and g are a subset of real numbers... t is continuous...